# Gotchas with template argument deduction for class templates

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, forwarding, forwarding-reference

I was reading the paper regarding template argument deduction for class templates here http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0091r3.html.  This feature is in the C++17 standard, and some things had confused me.

```
template <typename T>
class Something {
public:

    // delete the copy and move constructors for simplicity
    Something(const Something&) = delete;
    Something(Something&&) = delete;

    explicit Something(T&&) { ... }
    explicit Something(const T&) { ... }

    template <typename U, typename EnableIfNotT<U, T>* = nullptr>
    Something(U&&) { ... }
};
```

Given the above code, if someone tries to instantiate an instance of the above template like this

```
auto something = Something{std::shared_ptr<int>{}};
```

will the rvalue reference overload always be called?  Since the overload set considered for deduction is

```
template <typename T>
Something<T> F(T&&) { ... }
template <typename T>
Something<T> F(const T&) { ... }
template <typename T, typename U, typename EnableIfNotT<U, T>*>
Something<T> F(U&&) { ... }
```

1. The second overload will never be preferred over the first one (since that is now a forwarding reference overload, instead of being an rvalue reference overload), so what is supposed to happen here?
2. And it seems like the last one can never be called without explicitly specifying the `T` parameter, is this the intended behavior?
3. Also are there any other gotchas or style guidelines that one should keep in mind when using template argument deduction for class templates?
4. Further are user defined deduction guides required to be after the class definition?  For example, can you have the trailing return type in the declaration of the class constructor within the class definition itself? (Unlike the iterator constructor here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_deduction)

Comment: (1) The second overload is actually the same as the third overload, i.e. even you pass an lvalue it will choose the third one.  (2) No, just pass an lvalue to the constructor to have the third one called.  (3) Time will tell.  So far only few people are using it I guess.  (4) Seems like it, but I don't see a reason for this.  Perhaps it will change in the future.

Comment: Also, in your example nothing can work at all because all contructors are private and the definition of `EnableIfNotT` is missing (I guess it is `std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<U, T>::value>`)

Comment: @HenriMenke added the `public`, and that is what the enable if was.  I didn't mean for it to be a focus of the question.  How will the first template argument be deduced in the third case with a regular lvalue?

Comment: @HenriMenke, the enable if is just that but an additional `std::decay_t` should be added

Comment: The one thing that you shouldn't read for this feature is that paper. It took two extra papers to patch up the specification.

Comment: @T.C.  Could you link me to the latest description of this feature? Is the cppreference page the best place to look?

Comment: Well, the working paper would be the best, but if you aren't into that, the cppreference page looks reasonably complete and I don't spot any obvious problems with it.

Comment: @T.C. read the cppreference page, still seems like the problem of turning an rvalue reference to a forwarding reference problem still exists..

Comment: You clearly didn't read it carefully enough. Straight from the page: "An rvalue reference to a cv-unqualified template parameter is not a forwarding reference if that parameter is a class template parameter".

Comment: What do you mean by "will the rvalue reference overload always be called?"? You have only shown once scenario, so what does "always" mean here?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb I meant Similar to how forwarding reference functions are preferred to functions accepting `const T&`, even though they 'seem' to match better for non const lvalues.  For example https://wandbox.org/permlink/8KvHZXIjflD7pLXY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. The second overload will never be preferred over the first one (**since that is now a forwarding reference overload**, instead of being an rvalue reference overload), so what is supposed to happen here?

No, it is *not* a forwarding reference. This is a key distinction. From [[temp.deduct.call]](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp#deduct.call-3):

> A *forwarding reference* is an rvalue reference to a cv-unqualified template parameter that does not represent a template parameter of a class template (during class template argument deduction ([over.match.class.deduct])).

Your candidates are:

```
template <typename T>
Something<T> F(T&&);       // this ONLY matches non-const rvalues

template <typename T>
Something<T> F(const T&);  // this matches everything

template <typename T, typename U, typename EnableIfNotT<U, T>*>
Something<T> F(U&&);       // this matches nothing
```

When you write:

```
auto something = Something{std::shared_ptr<int>{}};
```

The `T&&` constructor is preferred, with `T=std::shared_ptr<int>`, so you end up with `Something<std::shared_ptr<int>>` as your class template specialization. If had instead written:

```
std::shared_ptr<int> p;
auto something = Something{p};
```

then the `T const&` constructor is preferred (indeed it is the only viable candidate). Although we end up in the same place: `Something<std::shared_ptr<int>>`.

> 2. And it seems like the last one can never be called without explicitly specifying the T parameter, is this the intended behavior?

Correct, `T` is a non-deduced context. This makes sense - this constructor exists to do conversions, but you need to specify what you're converting *to* in order to do the conversion. It would never make sense to have this "just work" for you.

> 4. Further are user defined deduction guides required to be after the class definition?

Yes. That's just where they go, by rule. It doesn't make sense to have trailing return type in the constructor - the constructor doesn't "return" anything.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  So the rules for forwarding references have been updated due to this change?  Also one more thing confused me from the link you included.  In the definition of `struct A` in the linked block of text, how is `T&&` in #3 a forwarding reference?  `T` there is a class template parameter right (and therefore should not be a forwarding reference)?

Comment: @Curious It's not a class template parameter, it's a deduction guide template parameter.

Comment: so when you write a deduction guide, what was not a forwarding reference now becomes a forwarding reference?  I feel like that is counter-intuitive, don't you think?  Do you have some insight as to why this is the way it is?

Comment: Also now that there is mandatory copy elision in the standard, I feel like including a trailing return type to a constructor is not completely wrong... Since a constructor does evaluate to a prvalue, just like a function returning a value.

Comment: @Curious There is no "what was... now becomes". These are not related things. In `template <class T> struct A { A(T&& ); }`, `T` isn't a forwarding reference - there is a constructor that takes an rvalue reference to `T`. That relationship is simply preserved when doing deduction. Nothing's changed.

Comment: So when you do add a forwarding reference deduction guide, then the previous rvalue constructor would never be preferred over the new forwarding reference constructor correct?  And the definition of the previous rvalue constructor would not assume that the parameter is a forwarding reference either..

Comment: @Curious Well, the rvalue constructor is more specialized, so it would be preferred in the case of rvalues.

Comment: Still a little confused, when you add a deduction guide as in the example, when you go to define the constructors you would have to define 3 instead of 2?  I thought the deduction guide was supposed to be for an existing constructor and not a separate function by itself..

Comment: @Curious A deduction guide is not "for an existing constructor" - it's for deduction. It's *only* necessary if the constructors are insufficient for deduction (e.g. the iterator-pair constructor for `std::vector`). It's *sole purpose* is to guide deduction. Your constructors should be defined based on what you actually need to construct your class.

Comment: So you would still only define two constructors in that example for `struct A`?  And in the rvalue constructor you would not expect a forwarding reference for the type `T` since you assume that its an rvalue, but the deduction guide will now match almost everything to that since according to the deduction guide the `T` is now a forwarding reference instead of an rvalue reference?

Comment: @Curious I don't understand what you're talking about, sorry.

Comment: here is what I mean https://ideone.com/a9Cb7h which constructors will be called in `main()` here?

Comment: @Curious What about the behavior of that program do you find confusing?

Comment: Doesn't the deduction guide say that the template parameter `T` is now a forwarding reference instead of an rvalue reference?  At least that is what I inferred from the example in the link you provided

Comment: @Curious I don't even understand what that question means. Here's a better [example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/xtqCsXg2EiL4TrVU). `U&&` is a forwarding reference, `T&&` is not a forwarding reference - it's an rvalue reference to `T`.

Comment: So I guess what I am trying to understand is, what does it even mean for `U&&` to be a forwarding reference?  Since a constructor with a forwarding reference parameter can never be called at all

Comment: IT'S NOT A CONSTRUCTOR. IT HAS NOTHING TO DO WITH CONSTRUCTION. The deduction guide exists **ONLY** to pick which `A<T>` you are constructing. AFTER you pick the `T`, THEN you go back and pick a constructor. Deducing `A{integer}` selects the deduction guide as the best match which gives you `U = int&`, so you end up with `A<int>`... then we basically do `A<int>{integer}`, which calls the `const T&` constructor.

Comment: Got it, thanks.  Sorry for the confusing line of questions.  I thought it was the same constructor but just with a return type explaining what the template parameter for the class would turn out to be.